# How to easily determine what's added/removed in a $scope.$watch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I am tasked with wrapping a JQuery-style UI component within an Angular directive. I have completed the task but it looks rather ugly. The underlying component's API only has `add` and `remove` methods for controlling a list of items. The only thing I can think to do is watch the two-way bound variable passed into my directive with `scope.$watchCollection` and then iterate over the old and new arguments to determine what has been added or removed, then invoke the add/remove API calls on the underlying component. This works, but I'm curious if there is a better way to accomplish this. The code is hideous and confusing.

Here is a demo minimal recreation of the component in it's natural habitat:

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/ofGeB?editors=101

You can see the component is instantiated on an element that has the items in the list within the markup. The component then returns an API to add/remove individual items. Please note that I have no control over the underlying component in our actual application and that the real component does far more than my demo component (which could easily be re-written with an ng-repeat).

Here is a demo minimal recreation of my directive wrapper:

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/LDgCF?editors=101

This works great and simulates a two-way bound variable with a jquery-style component that only has add/remove methods for individual items. I want to know if there is a better way to determine new/removed items within `$watchCollection`.

```
  // Watch items for changes.
  scope.$watchCollection('items', function (newItemList, oldItemList) {
    // Iterate over the newItemList and determine what items are new.
    if (newItemList) {
      newItemList.forEach(function (newItem) {
        var addItem = true;
        if (oldItemList) {
          oldItemList.forEach(function (oldItem) {
            if (newItem === oldItem) {
              addItem = false;
            }            
          });
        }
        if (addItem) {
          listApi.addItem(newItem);
        }
      });
    }
    // Iterate over the oldItemList and determine what was removed.
    if (oldItemList) {
      oldItemList.forEach(function (oldItem, oldItemIndex) {
        var removeItem = true;
        if (newItemList) {
          newItemList.forEach(function (newItem) {
            if (oldItem === newItem) {
              removeItem = false;
            }
          });
        }
        if (removeItem) {
          listApi.removeItem(oldItemIndex);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

All of that just to determine what should be added or removed using the component API whenever the collection changes. Is this the best way? I ask because I've been finding myself writing similar logic repeatedly and wondered if there may be a more proper and/or simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(arr) {
    return this.filter(function(el) { return arr.indexOf(el) < 0; });
};

var addedItems = newItemList.diff(oldItemList);
var removedItems = oldItemList.diff(newItemList);
```

Comment: Elegant in its simplicity. Even if performance isn't any faster at least the code is much simpler. Thank you.